# Is Reliable collections data after application removal alive?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have a `IReliableDictionary`. Every time I remove the application and deploy it again, I expect that all the data will be erased.

But it looks like something persists on disk and the dictionary is able to load this data after redeploy. So when I try to `AddAsync` something after redeploy I get the `ArgumentException` with additional information `key`. Looks like I'm trying to insert already inserted key.

The name of the dictionary is the same and the whole cluster isn't redeployed, only application itself.

Is it a normal behavior? Because I can't insert a new value after redeploy and it seems logically incorrect.

**Local dev cluster**, SF version 2.1.163.

Comment: Are you deploying to Azure or to the Local Dev Cluster?

Comment: @LoekD local dev cluster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you're using the right deploy mode in Visual Studio. It has two ways to deploy applications locally:

- Auto Upgrade
- Remove

**Remove** will remove an application completely, removing all state, and then redeploy a new application.

**Auto Upgrade** will perform a rolling upgrade so that you don't lose state. This is handy when you're working on an application that needs to be loaded up with data to test it, so you don't lose all your test data every time you make a code change and run the application.

Right click on your application project and go to properties to set this:

[image]

Comment: I'm sure that I use *Remove* mode. All the processes except for fabric internal got killed and I have only two place where such things is happening — both in statefull services with reliable dictionary. There are plenty of other services and they behave differently,

Comment: I found the root cause. Deep down inside the project there was code that added data to the collections and it was hard to find it quickly. But strange that removing of cluster helped once.